# How can I bundle a Python script with module dependencies into a package or .exe file?

Tags: python, windows-installer, pyinstaller

I have following dependencies for my script

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from sklearn import neighbors
import itertools
import math
import time
PATH_XGBOOST = "./xgboost/wrapper/"
PATH_MODEL = './models/model.model'

import sys
sys.path.insert(1,PATH_XGBOOST)
import xgboost as xgb
```

For this script I wouild like to package all the stuff and run it on another machine without any package or library installation but only python installed. (preferably package on Linux and run on Windows) Is there any way to do so ? As far as I search there are pyinstaller and py2exe but I cannot deal with them, I guess due to the xgboost libaray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [cx_freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze)

If you want to freeze using distutil script follow [this](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html) steps

Comment: I guess it has a common problem in Windows environment. It raises an error for collections.sys .